# How Do I Access Properties of an Object Selected from a ListBox WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a list box bound to an observable object in my ViewModel. When the user selects an item in the listbox the SelectedItem fires the "SelectedSandwich" property. The value is saved to a private field. The properties SandwichName and Description are properties of the Sandwich object. I want text blocks in my view to show selected sandwichname and price, but I don't want to bind these text blocks to the listbox element.
Here is the view:
    '

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:SandwichVM/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="lstSandwich">
        <Border BorderThickness="3" 
                CornerRadius="4" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                BorderBrush="Blue">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Run Text="{Binding SandwichName}"/>
                <Run Text=" | " />
                <Run Text="{Binding Description}" />
                <Run Text=" | " />
                <Run Text="{Binding Price}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="menu" >
        <Border>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Run Text="{Binding SandwichName}"/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Price}" />
            </TextBlock>  
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="cboMenu" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Sandwiches}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSandwich, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lstSandwich}"
             Margin="3">
    </ListBox>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   FontStretch="ExtraExpanded" 
                   FontFamily="Verdana"
                   FontSize="22"
                   >
            <Run Text="Your Selection"/>
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl 
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource menu}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="5,0,5,0">
            </ContentControl>
           </Grid>
       </Grid>


   </Grid>
</Window>'
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
'class SandwichVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Sandwich _selectedSandwich;
    private ObservableCollection<Sandwich> _sandwiches;



    public ObservableCollection<Sandwich> Sandwiches 
    {
        get { return _sandwiches; }
    }


    public SandwichVM()
    {
        //fake data for the list
        _sandwiches = new ObservableCollection<Sandwich>();
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Pastrami", "Stacked high on rye bread     with a touch of mustard.", 8.50));
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Tuna", "Fresh tuna salad on wheat with slice of cheddar cheese.", 6.50));
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Steak", "Sliced grilled steak with sauteed mushrooms and onions.", 9.50));
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Chicken Salad", "Juicy chunks of chicken breast, onions, fruit.", 6.50));
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Buffalo Chicken", "Caliente! Fried chicken breast slathered with hot buffalo wing sauce.", 8.50));
        _sandwiches.Add(new Sandwich("Tofu", "I don't know how to make a tofu sandwich.", 1.50));

    }

    public Sandwich SelectedSandwich
    {
        get { return _selectedSandwich; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedSandwich != value)
            {
                _selectedSandwich = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedSandwich");
            }
        } 
    }

    public string SandwichName
    {
        get { return _selectedSandwich.SandwichName; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSandwich.SandwichName = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SandwichName");
        }

    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _selectedSandwich.Description; }
        set
        {
            _selectedSandwich.Description = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Description");
        }
    }

    public string Price
    {
        get { return _selectedSandwich.Price.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            _selectedSandwich.Price = Convert.ToDouble(value);
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Price");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }'
```

I tried putting the RaisePropertyChangedEvent in the setters for the three properties (though I only need to read them) but the setters are never executed. In fact, the setter for the SelectedSandwich property is never executed. The get is executed everytime. I have stepped through the code but can't see where the problem lies.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its not clear to me, but the only property you are setting from UI is the SelectedSandwich property. If it sets properly when you change the selected listbox item then why not to bind to the SelectedSandwich from the other place?

So if you want some text blocks in your view to show selected sandwichname and price just try something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedSandwich.Name}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedSandwich.Price}"/>
```

Or if you want to use your prepared datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sandwichVMNamespace:Sandwich}">
    <Border>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Run Text="{Binding SandwichName}"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Price}" />
        </TextBlock>  
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
   <ContentControl 
      Content="{Binding SelectedSandwich}" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Margin="5,0,5,0">
   </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

And you are done...

Comment: Your first example was one of my trials. I don't get anything. I keep looking for some sort of typo. There is something very simple that I am missing. Your second example won't run or won't compile, depending on what I do. The Namespace is ComboBox (I know, but I started with a combobox). I just noticed the top of the viewmodel is not there. I have xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ComboBox.ViewModel". Then,as you can see I have the data context set on the window. So I don't understand the "x:Type" you propose.

Comment: The DataTemplate is the one you called x:Key="menu" and the grid is the one you have at the bottom of xaml page just paste it. There is no reason why it should not compile... Dont bother with x:Type the important think is "sandwichVMNamespace:Sandwich" you have to specify the namespace of your Sandwich class as you did before, maybe something like xmlns:sandwichVMNamespace="clr-namespace:ComboBox.ViewModel". And its all done because of the great wpf...